# Save CSV file to kdb+ table

Tags: node.js, kdb

I have a CSV file called `candlesData.csv`(~300MB). I want to create a new table in kdb+ called `candles` and have the CSV data be there for faster reading while I use it on my app.
I opened a terminal and typed:

```
show candles:("IJFFFFFJFIFFF"; enlist",") 0: `:path/to/file/candlesData.csv
```

It shows all the data perfectly. The problem is now how do I store it permanently on the DB.
If I exit with `\\` and type `q` again, if I type `candles` it shows an error.

How do I save this CSV to a table that I can get anytime? and how to access this table afterwards with nodeJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `set` keyword. If you know what the root of the path is to your database, you can just do

```
`:path/to/db/candles set candles
```

Then when you start q again, if you run

```
q path/to/db
```

it should load in your table

```
 λ mkdir db
 λ q
KDB+ 3.6 2019.09.19 Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Kx Systems

q)`:db/table set ([] a: 1 2 3)
`:db/table
q)\\
 λ q db
KDB+ 3.6 2019.09.19 Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Kx Systems

q)table
a
-
1
2
3
q)
```

In your case, you would run

```
q)candles:("IJFFFFFJFIFFF"; enlist",") 0: `:path/to/file/candlesData.csv
q)`:path/to/db/candles set candles
```

This is a great resource for this kind of thing:

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb+/